# Lubuntu 19.04 for System Tools > Users and Groups

Tags: users

On Lubuntu 18.04 I would add users via System Tools > Users and Groups. How is this done on Lubuntu 19.04 as there is no "Users and Groups" under "System Tools " as there is in 18.04.

18.04:

[image: Lubuntu 18.04 System Tools > Users and Groups]

19.04:

[image: Lubuntu 19.04 System Tools >]

Comment: I confirm there's no "Users and Groups" under "System Tools" AKA gnome-control-center in Ubuntu 19.04, as 18.04 provides, so this isn't a Lubuntu issue, but an Ubuntu issue. Interim releases are sometime a little rough around the edges, and don't offer the stability and completeness which LTS releases do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferences > LXQt settings >  Users and Groups

19.04:

[image: 19.04: Preferences > LXQt settings > Users and Groups]

Answer (score 0):

Please try the Ubuntu method; search on [Users](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-add.html.en) and an app should appear. If not, try the command line version [outlined here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/user-management.html.en):

```
sudo adduser username
```

Comment: Answer rewritten accordingly. You may wish to consider submitting a bug report https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs